How to interpret the partition function when written using Virasoro characters in a BCFT?
I am probably missing a basic point here but I am struggling to interpret the differences between the Virasoro character representations of the partition function for usual CFTs vs their BCFT counterparts. Consider the partition function of a compactified boson on a torus (from section 10.4.1 of the yellow book):
$$
Z = \frac{1}{|\eta(\tau)|^2}\sum_{e,m\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{(e/R + mR/2)^2/2}\bar{q}^{(e/R - mR/2)^2/2}.
$$
The partition function above can be thought of as being the generating function of the conformal dimensions $(h,\bar{h})$ of all the primaries where $h =(e/R + mR/2)^2/2 $ and $\bar{h}=(e/R - mR/2)^2/2$. Now take the partition function of a boundary CFT of a compactified boson with Dirichlet boundary conditions on both ends of the system as (see equation A12 in this):
$$
Z^{DD} = \frac{1}{\eta(q)}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q^{g(k+z)^2}, 
$$
where the symbols are defined in the given source. Here, the partition function has the interpretation of being the generating function for the boundary spectrum only. What about the primaries in the bulk? Shouldn't the above be the spectrum for all primaries in the theory like the first case, be it in the bulk or the boundary?
